# Can I have multiple CSS classes in a complex specification?

Tags: css

Is there a more compact way to expresss

```
dl.class dt em,
dl.data dt em,
dl.exception dt em,
dl.attribute dt em,
dl.method dt em,
dl.class dt big,
dl.data dt big,
dl.exception dt big,
dl.attribute dt big,
dl.method dt big
{
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

For example, something like

```
dl(.class, .data, .exception, .attribute, .method) dt (em, big) {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Not with pure CSS.  [Less](http://www.lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) let you write your code like this, then compile to CSS.

Comment: LESS can do this.  http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

Comment: Assuming you can target all dl in a given id or element, #id dl dt em {} and #id dl dt big {}

Comment: @SLaks - nice article.  You explore some uses of `&` that I hadn't considered.

Comment: @SLaks: So without LESS or Sass, they way I've done it is the only way (unless there's a more clever way to parse the HTML where the styles are used)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius you can add an extra universal attribute to the target dl and target it that. something like dl[title].... but then again, you can just add a class to all of them instead

Comment: do you use the attribute, method, etc. classes any where else? If not, then you can remove the dl tag. 

Do you have any other ems or bigs at their parents level or in their parents siblings? if not you can omit the dt's? 

If you answered no to both questions, you can just write .class em, .class big, .method em, .method big, etc.. you get the idea. If you answered yes to either, then you need to use less/sass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done in the current version of CSS, however there are some proposals of this nature in [Selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches), which are prototyped in some browsers. For example in Firefox you can use `:-moz-any` like this:

```
:-moz-any(dl.class, dl.data, dl.exception, dl.attribute, dl.method) dt :-moz-any(em, big)
{
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/km76V/3/) of how this would work.